# data not setting in session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
//uploading product movie or image?
        if($this->input->post('upload_360') == "Upload") {
            $config['upload_path'] = './media/images/products/360s';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'swf';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('film')) {
                $this->data['product_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            } else {
                $this->data['data_360'] = $this->upload->data();
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('360_film' => $this->data['data_360']));
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('advantages' => $this->input->post('product_advantages')));
            $this->data['session_advantages'] = $this->session->userdata('advantages');
        }
        //upload the product image, if successful the user will be
        //notified if the image is too high or wide, and will be offered,
        //the chance to crop the image. All cropping takes place in the media
        //controller.
        if($this->input->post('product_image') == "Upload") {
            $config['upload_path'] = './media/images/products/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_upload')) {
                //die("!");
                $this->data['image_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            } else {
                $this->data['image_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('image' => $this->data['image_data']));
                $this->data['session_image'] = $this->session->userdata('image');
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('advantages' => $this->input->post('product_advantages')));
            $this->data['session_advantages'] = $this->session->userdata('advantages');
        }

        if($this->input->post('screenshot_upload') == "Upload") {
            $config['upload_path'] = './media/images/products/360s/screenshots/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('screenshot')) {
                //die("!");
                $this->data['screenshot_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            } else {
                $this->data['screenshot_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('screenshot' => $this->data['screenshot_data']));
                $this->data['session_screenshot'] = $this->session->userdata('screenshot');
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('advantages' => $this->input->post('product_advantages')));
            $this->data['session_advantages'] = $this->session->userdata('advantages');
        }
```

On my form I have the user choose a file and the click an upload button dependent on which button is clicked the file gets uploaded and the upload data gets saved in a session.

The session is then used to get data from to save to a database, the upload_360 session works, the product_image session works fine but the screenshot_upload session only has data when with the if statement (3rd one in the code) if I try and acccess it outside of the code then that portion of the session is empty?

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Any errors? what type of session are you using. Codeigniters cookies, database, native session, or phpsession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing data in a session before inserting it into the db?

Cookies can only hold 4KB of data...

> but the screenshot_upload session only has data when with the if statement (3rd one in the code) if I try and acccess it outside of the code then that portion of the session is empty?

I don't understand that part of your question. Do you mean it only has data when only using the 3rd `if` statement? i.e. when only trying to do `screenshot_upload` and not `product_image` or 360_upload`? If so, that might speak to the cookie size limit.

Instead of

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('screenshot' => $this->data['screenshot_data']));
$this->data['session_screenshot'] = $this->session->userdata('screenshot');
```

why don't you

```
$this->uploads_model->insert_screenshot_data($this->data['screenshot_data']);//send screenshot upload_data to model to be inserted into db
$this->data['screenshot_data'] = $this->data['screenshot_data'];//if you want to pass screenshot upload_data to template/view
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending output to the user before setting the session (I'm inferring this from the $this->template->build, which is custom code.)

The session, like headers, cannot be modified after anything (ANYTHING) has been sent to output. This is because the session itself is sent in the header.